# Theorem 5 of the paper "A periodic group with almost regular involutions"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I Just want to know the exact statement of Theorem 5 of this paper "V. P. Sunkov, Periodic group with almost regular involutions, Algebra i Logika, 7(1) (1968), 113-121. I have tried to download this paper, but it is not there in the internet.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

(Click on the image to enlarge it.)

Comment: I have been struggle a lot to find this paper, but to no avail. Thanks.